# Laravel Auth()->user()->id is null when I try to call API

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry, I'm still new to Laravel.
I have a Laravel app, that has an API route, which should ask for the Timer, of the logged in person, however it always returns null.

This is my `App\Http\Controllers\Api\TimerController.php`

```php
public function index(){
        dd(Auth()->user()->id);
        return Timer::where('userID', Auth()->user()->id)->first();
    }
```

My `routes\api.php`

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('timer', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\TimerController@index');
```

And after this I have a vue frontend application that processes the data it receives.
However I really do only want to give through the API the logged in persons data.
Am I missing something, that prevents me from checking if I'm logged in or not? Because in the other Controllers I can check the login of a person with `Auth()->user()->id`, but not in this one.

Answer (score 0):

You get auth user's id null when your request couldn't be authentiacated by Sanctum. So this is a token issue. Add this line under axios code which should be in bootstrap.js file.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

If you make API calls to outside your app, and get error, make this value false inside the function that will make the call.

Comment: I added this code to Bootstrap.js ran the npm run dev, but the `Auth()->user()` is still null

Comment: In this case your Sanctum configurations should be incorrect.

Comment: BTW the methos is not Auth(), it should be auth(). Since it didn't say undefined method, Auth works porbably, but it should be all lower case.

Comment: Auth() is working, and returns a null at user() and with guard being null too. 
I'll try to set up sanctum again then, and hope for the best.